# Rearranging UITableView rows - fromIndexPath and toIndexPath the same

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having trouble rearranging the rows in my `tableView`. The table is in editing mode, and all relevant methods are overridden to return `YES`:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    NSLog(@"From: %d to: %d", fromIndexPath.row, toIndexPath.row);
    // some code to modify the dataSource
    // ...
}
```

What happens is that while the rearranging control is showing, if I try to drag it, it only moves the row a tiny bit, and then `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` gets called and both `fromIndexPath` and `toIndexPath` are the same!

Upon further examination it appears that sometimes I manage to flick the row up or down fast enough that it actually works, but moves it only 1 row at a time.

I have another app where I can rearrange rows slowly and easily, but here once I start dragging, it seems to want to commit the change after a fraction of a second, so if I did not move it far enough, it just jumps back to its original row. What's causing it?

Comment: you need to show some more code here... tableView setup / your dataSource changes.. if you have an empty clean project dragging works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful consideration I realized that this issue was due to the UI layer of the app, not `tableView` configuration. The culprit was a side menu module that I added to the app, which by default adds a `UIGestureRecognizer` to detect when a user swipes the screen to reveal the menu on the side. It was interfering with default gesture recognizers of the `tableView`, and once disabled, everything works fine. Watch out for these undesirable side effects when using third party libraries :)